# WP Widget instances and options

Tags: wordpress

When I activate my plugin I add some values to the options database, e.g.

```
add_option('code','55');
```

How do I update that value or use it in the widget? I only see "instances" now, like the example on this page:

http://wpcoderz.com/creating-a-multi-instance-widget-with-wordpress-2-8/

I've gone through all of the widget API, but no go.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan, the code for a widget isn't special, so to obtain the value of options set with add_option(), just use get_option() as usual - and update_option() to update it.

Not sure what you meant by 'instances' - the link seems broken.